# Count Number of Occurrences of words from a list in text entries (R)

Tags: r, string, text

I am working with a set of tweets pulled from Twitter's public API and am trying to do a bit of text analysis.

Currently, I have a data frame for the tweets and the text is housed in the column titled `total.tweets$text` and has entries like:

I have a dictionary of sentiment-words (i.e. - positive, negative, etc) and pulled each column in from the csv file as a string:

> posTerms <- toString(na.omit(lexicon$Positiv))

I would like to count the number of times any positive from this file appears in each tweet, creating a new column for that count that would be `total.tweets$PosCount`.

For example, a tweet that reads: `Our greatest glory is not in never falling, but in rising every time we fall #confucius #entrepreneurship`

If `greatest` `glory` and `rising` are in the positive words, the PosCount would be 3.

I tried using `strcount` as below:

```
posTerms <- toString(na.omit(lexicon$Positiv))
```

total.tweets$Positiv <- str_count(total.tweets$text, paste(posTerms,collapse='|'))

But keep getting this error:

> Error: invalid regular expression 'ABIDE, ABILITY, ABLE, ABOUND,. . .

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work using the %in% operator

```
lexicon = c("greatest" ,"glory" , "rising")
sentence = "Our greatest glory is not in never falling, but in rising every time we fall #confucius #entrepreneurship"
```

Split the sentence into words using strsplit

```
words = strsplit(sen," ")

sum(words[[1]] %in% lexicon) #returns the number of words that matches lexicon
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `stringi` package:

```
text <- "Our greatest glory is not in never falling, but in rising every time we fall #confucius #entrepreneurship"
search <- c("greatest", "glory","rising")
require(stringi)
stri_detect_fixed(text, search)
## [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE
sum(stri_detect_fixed(text, search))
## [1] 3
```